# How can I capture form values into rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<div class="col-md-10">
            <%= f.radio_button :recipients, 'Resources', checked: true %> Resources<br />
            <%= f.radio_button :recipients, 'Organisations', checked: true %> Organisations<br />
        <br/>
        </br/>
</div>
```

I have this radio button in my form and I'd like the form  to be able to pass that into the model/controller if Organisations is selected then recipient will be Organisations. Please help I'm still new to Ruby

Comment: `params[:recipients]` capture using that

Comment: Submit the form, then look at the window where you started your server, and examine the server output.  You should see something like: `Parameters: {......}`.  Copy and paste that line into your question.  Rails assigns that Hash to the variable `params`, which is available in any of your action methods.

Comment: By the way, in an action method you can always write `puts "[ME]: #{some_variable}"`, then look in the server window for the output.

Comment: So how should the syntax be like?

`if params[:recipients] = Resources`

Comment: @MrNash, You need to post the output I asked for in my first comment.  Post the output at the bottom of your question. If you do, we can tell you exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @7stud here's the result 
`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YzFNk2cSNWU5DarWw4B1dMJYDX4mc==", "broadcast"=>{"subject"=>"Test email", "message"=>"This is an
organisation test email", "recipients"=>"Organisations", "country_id"=>"1", "skill_id"=>"", "id"=>["", "7", "5", "8"]}, "commit"=>"Send"}`

Comment: @MrNash, See my answer, it was too long to type into a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is the hash:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YzFNk2cSNWU5DarWw4B1dMJYDX4mc==",
"broadcast"=>{"subject"=>"Test email", 
"message"=>"This is an organisation test email",
"recipients"=>"Organisations",
"country_id"=>"1", "skill_id"=>"", "id"=>["", "7", "5", "8"]}, "commit"=>"Send"}
```

Rails assigns that hash to a variable named `params`:

```
params = {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YzFNk2cSNWU5DarWw4B1dMJYDX4mc==",
    "broadcast"=>{"subject"=>"Test email", 
    "message"=>"This is an organisation test email",
    "recipients"=>"Organisations",
    "country_id"=>"1", "skill_id"=>"", "id"=>["", "7", "5", "8"]}, "commit"=>"Send"}
```

Although it may be a little hard to make out, `params["broadcast"]` has the value:

```
{
"subject"=>"Test email", 
"message"=>"This is an organisation test email",
"recipients"=>"Organisations", 
"country_id"=>"1", 
"skill_id"=>"", 
"id"=>["", "7", "5", "8"]
}
```

To get that hash into a variable, you can write:

```
form_data = params["broadcast"]
```

That is equivalent to:

```
form_data = {
    "subject"=>"Test email", 
    "message"=>"This is an organisation test email",
    "recipients"=>"Organisations", 
    "country_id"=>"1", 
    "skill_id"=>"", 
    "id"=>["", "7", "5", "8"]
}
```

That hash contain's all the key/value pairs from your form.  Each key corresponds to the name attribute of one of the input fields in the form, and the value is the value of that input field.  You should look at the `Page Source` in your browser to examine the html created by your form. Locate the form in the html source and examine the name attribute of each input field.  Also, see the Rails Guide on [Binding a form to an Object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) for some examples of the html created by your form.

Finally, you can get the value of the "recipient" key in the `form_data` hash like this:

```
if form_data["recipient"] == "Organisations"
  ...
  ...
end
```

Because `form_data` is equivalent to `params["broadcast"]`, you can substitute `params["broadcast"]` in place of `form_data` in the if-statement, giving you:

```
   |<--form_data---->| 
   |                 |
if params["broadcast"]["recipient"] == "Organisations"
  ...
  ...
end
```

Comment: this is the error I'm getting when I use `form_data`

`NameError (undefined local variable or method `form_data' for #<Broadcast:0xd01a150>):` but using `params["broadcast"]["recipient"] == "Organisations"` seems to be working, thank you

Comment: @MrNash, In ruby, you can create a variable at will:  *To get that hash into a variable, you can write: `form_data = params["broadcast"]`*.  Was that in your code? You can't skip steps.  Because I suspected that you would not understand what this means:  `params["broadcast"]["recipient"]`, I created an intermediate step to help you understand how to get information out of a nested hash.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using something like form_for(@model_name) helper, then params[:model_name][:recipients] will help you retrieve the desired value.

Whereas if you're using form_tag helper, then you can get the same value using params[:recipient].

Comment: Doesn't the syntax of the form elements preclude `form_tag()`?